# Jquery slideshow with ui color change

Tags: jquery, css, class, user-interface, slideshow

I have searched and searched, trying to find a simple jQuery slideshow or script that can set a class depending on some attribute on the div that is active.

Like the link, does when changing image and color of the Ui to match the background-image
http://www.squarespace.com/#startups

Can some one help me or point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own problem:

```
$(function(){
    $('#slider div:first-child').addClass('active');

    $('.arrow').on('click', function(){
        updateClass( $(this).attr('data-dir') );
        var itemType = $('#slider').find('div.active').data('uicolor');
        if ( itemType == 'light' )
        {
            $('body').removeClass("darkui");
            $('body').addClass("lightui");
        }
        else if ( itemType == 'dark' )
        {
            $('body').removeClass("lightui");
            $('body').addClass("darkui");
        }
        return false;
    });

});

function updateClass ( direction )
{
    var current = $('#slider .active');

    if ( direction == 'left' && current.index() > 0 )
    {
        current.removeClass('active');
        current.prev().addClass('active');
    }
    else if ( direction == 'right' && current.index() < $('#slider div:last-child').index() )
    {
        current.removeClass('active');
        current.next().addClass('active');
    }
}

$("#slider div:first-child").addClass("active");
var itemType = $('#slider').find('div.active').data('uicolor');
if ( itemType == 'light' )
{
    $('body').removeClass("darkui");
    $('body').addClass("lightui");
}
else if ( itemType == 'dark' )
{
    $('body').removeClass("lightui");
    $('body').addClass("darkui");
}
setTimeout(autoAddClass, 7000);

function autoAddClass(){
    var next = $(".active").removeClass("active").next();
    if(next.length)
        $(next).addClass('active');
        var itemType = $('#slider').find('div.active').data('uicolor');
            if ( itemType == 'light' )
            {
                $('body').removeClass("darkui");
                $('body').addClass("lightui");
            }
            else if ( itemType == 'dark' )
            {
                $('body').removeClass("lightui");
                $('body').addClass("darkui");
            }
    else
        $('#slider div:first-child').addClass('active');
    setTimeout(autoAddClass, 7000);
}
```